# Installing node with homebrew on OSX. Npm not found

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew

I previously had a working install of node and npm on OSX, but when updating npm something went wrong. I then messed things up more using homebrew to try and link, uninstall, and reinstall node. Somewhere along the way my original node install, which used the installer from nodejs.com, and my brew usage on node conflicted. I finally got node reinstall with homebrew, but when I try running npm I get the npm command not found. Here is the message I get when running brew install node.

```
$ brew install node
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/node-0.10.3
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/node-0.10.32.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring node-0.10.32.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
==> make install
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
make: *** [install] Error 3
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall node`
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.32: 1678 files, 19M
```

I tried running the postinstall node as stated in the error message but then get this error message.

```
$ brew postinstall node
==> make install
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
make: *** [install] Error 3
```

Any ideas of how to fix my node install?

Here's the last part of the npm-debug.log

```
30 silly resolved     readmeFilename: 'README.md',
30 silly resolved     _id: 'npm@1.4.24',
30 silly resolved     _shasum: 'c0b916c7b6363d1fbde42c2d1420aca8e05a4118',
30 silly resolved     _from: '.' } ]
31 info install npm@1.4.24 into /usr/local/lib
32 info installOne npm@1.4.24
33 verbose lib/node_modules/npm unbuild
34 info preuninstall npm@1.4.24
35 info uninstall npm@1.4.24
36 verbose true,/usr/local/lib/node_modules,/usr/local/lib/node_modules unbuild npm@1.4.24
37 verbose /usr/local/bin,[object Object] binRoot
38 verbose lib/node_modules/npm unbuild
39 info preuninstall npm@1.4.24
40 info uninstall npm@1.4.24
41 verbose true,/usr/local/lib/node_modules,/usr/local/lib/node_modules unbuild npm@1.4.24
42 verbose /usr/local/bin,[object Object] binRoot
43 error error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/share/man/man5/npm-folders.5'
43 error error rolling back  npm@1.4.24 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/share/man/man5/npm-folders.5']
43 error error rolling back   errno: 3,
43 error error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
43 error error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/share/man/man5/npm-folders.5' }
44 error Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/share/man/man5/npm-folders.5'
44 error  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/share/man/man5/npm-folders.5']
44 error   errno: 3,
44 error   code: 'EACCES',
44 error   path: '/usr/local/share/man/man5/npm-folders.5' }
45 error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
46 error System Darwin 13.4.0
47 error command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/cli.js" "install" "-g" "-f"
48 error cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
49 error node -v v0.10.32
50 error npm -v 1.4.24
51 error path /usr/local/share/man/man5/npm-folders.5
52 error code EACCES
53 error errno 3
54 error stack Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/share/man/man5/npm-folders.5'
55 verbose exit [ 3, true ]
```

Comment: Can you post the `npm-debug.log` as well?

Comment: The log is really long. From what I've read on other sites most the useful information in the log is at the end of it. Should I just post The last part? Sorry I have never had to look at a log like this before

Comment: Post the part which contains "error" wording, or copy to pastebin.com

Comment: I edited the question with the error part of the log. Sorry the log is really cryptic to me I am new to the node environment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do yourself a favor and use [`nvm`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). It helps you manage Node versions and you won't need root priviledges to use it.

## Install `nvm`

Here we're using `curl` to get the install script for `nvm` and interpreting that script using `bash`.

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.17.2/install.sh | bash
```

## Install `node` + `npm`

This command will figure out the latest stable release of `node` and install it in your system.

```
nvm install stable
```

<sub>([currently bugged](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/546), use `nvm install 0.10` for now...)</sub>

## Persist

So that `nvm` configures your terminal whenever you open a new window, run this command too:

```
nvm alias default stable
```

<sub>([currently bugged](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/546), use `nvm alias default 0.10` for now...)</sub>

## Use

Now you can use Node as usual!

```
node foo
```

## Read `nvm` documentation!

Here: https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: nvm install stable command give me version stable is not found. Using the nvm ls-remote command shows me all the versions. Should I just use the newest one listed? Or is that version not going to be very stable being new?

Comment: Yeah using the latest one should just work too. e.g: `nvm install 0.10`

Comment: Thank you so much! I have read random things about nvm, but I didn't know what it was. I've been trying to fix this for a few hours now and this made it such a simple fix.

Comment: By the way, stable means the `0.10` (or "even") branch and unstable means the `0.11` (or "odd") branch. That's just the convention Node versioning uses

Comment: Thank you for that. I kinda figured that was the case but wasn't sure. Everything is working now, but using npm install -g sails, to try and install sails is giving me two npm WARN deprecated grunt-lib contrib@0.7.1 and another error. I wasn't sure if this issue was related to the version of node installed with nvm that you provided or if this was a completely separate issue altogether.

Comment: The lastest stable version is v0.12.1

Comment: The only hassle with this answer is that on a fresh install of OSX after running the first curl command it tells you to close and reopen your terminal window, which then tells you that nvm can't be found.

Comment: I didn't have a ~/.bash_profile and the script didn't warn me (i think) so all I had to do was run touch ~/.bash_profile and then rerun the command. This then told me everything was up to date so I removed the .nvm directory, then reran the first curl command and then closed and opened the terminal window and then all was well. I think you should update your answer for this case.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to permissions problems with Homebrew is often `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)`. If you ever used npm as root, which should not be necessary, some of the files in its directory tree will be owned by root, which will cause permissions problems on upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

I am on OSX and fixed this issue by downloading and installing the latest version from http://nodejs.org/. This will get you the latest node and npm.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't going to be the accepted answer, but you probably have done something like `sudo npm -g install XXX` previously and now have some permission trouble.

There are two spots where this trouble will get you:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami`:staff /Users/`whoami` /usr/local
```

The gist is that Node keeps some things in /usr/local and NPM keeps some things in your HOME directory. If you touched any of those with `sudo` you'll have bad time.

Comment: Yeah that is what happened. And I did have a bad time! Luckily using nvm fixed my issue.

Comment: Brew works just fine, just don't `sudo npm` and you won't have any trouble. I hear good things for NVM from the Linux side though.

Answer (score 0):

If npm -v gives an error after installing node , it shows that symlink is not created.Whenever an install via brew happens , there will be a symlink creation.
If installing some packages results in warning , u have to use the **export command shown in the warning at ur respective workspace folder**